# EXT Multiple Paging Toolbars Only 1 Works

Tags: javascript, extjs, ext.net

My basic problem is this, I have a page with 3 grids, all of which have paging toolbars. All grid render on page load. When the page loads, only 1 of the 3 toolbars actually works. The other 2 don't show page numbers, and all buttons are greyed out. I've tried everything I can think of, but if they all populate on page load, only 1 works. If they render separately, say with a button click on the page, the toolbars work perfectly.

Has anyone else had this issue and solved it?

Comment: Provide us a fiddle, please.

Comment: Do you have an `<ext:PagingToolbar>` configured in the either the TopBar or BottomBar of each GridPanel? They should theoretically automatically hook up the correct event handlers to trigger the paging independently of each other. Does each GridPanel use the same `<ext:Store>`, or unique instances?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Each grid has a PagingToolbar in the BottomBar. Each has it's own Store.

I will work on a fiddle, but what I have is all written in EXT.NET so it will take me a while.

Comment: I guess it has been asked in the [Ext.NET forums](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?59802) as well. Also there is a related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/extnet/Ext.NET/issues/727). In brief, it was a bug in Ext.NET which has been fixed in Ext.NET 3.1.0 release and also for Ext.NET 2, but in SVN (branches/2) only.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Grid and Multiple Paging Toolbar in single Window on page Load in Extjs

```
 Ext.onReady(function () {
            var userStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                autoLoad: 'false',
                fields: [
                    { name: 'name' },
                    { name: 'email' },
                    { name: 'phone' }
                ],
                data: [
                    { name: 'Lisa', email: 'lisa@simpsons.com', phone: '555-111-1224' },
                    { name: 'Bart', email: 'bart@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1234' },
                    { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1244' },
                    { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' },
                    { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1244' },
                    { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' },
                ]
            });
            var userStore1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                autoLoad: 'false',
                fields: [
                    { name: 'name' },
                    { name: 'email' },
                    { name: 'phone' }
                ],
                data: [
                    { name: 'Lisa', email: 'lisa@simpsons.com', phone: '555-111-1224' },
                    { name: 'Bart', email: 'bart@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1234' },
                    { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1244' },
                    { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' },

                ]
            });
            var userStore2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                autoLoad: 'false',
                fields: [
                    { name: 'name' },
                    { name: 'email' },
                    { name: 'phone' }
                ],
                data: [
                    { name: 'Lisa', email: 'lisa@simpsons.com', phone: '555-111-1224' },
                    { name: 'Bart', email: 'bart@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1234' },
                    { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1244' },
                    { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' },
                    { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1244' },
                    { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' },
                    { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' },
                    { name: 'Homer', email: 'homer@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1244' },
                    { name: 'Marge', email: 'marge@simpsons.com', phone: '555-222-1254' },
                ]
            });
            Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                height: 600,
                width: 400,
                xtype: 'panel',
                layout: 'fit',
                title:'Multiple Grid and Multiple Toolbar in single Window on page Load',
                items:
                [
                    {
                        layout: 'border',
                        height: 350,
                        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                        items:
                           [
                               {
                                   xtype: 'panel',
                                   region: 'north',
                                   layout: 'fit',
                                   items: [
                                           {
                                               xtype: 'grid',

                                               store: userStore1,
                                               columns: [
                             {
                                 header: 'Name',
                                 width: 100,
                                 sortable: false,
                                 hideable: false,
                                 dataIndex: 'name'
                             },
                             {
                                 header: 'Email Address',
                                 width: 150,
                                 dataIndex: 'email',
                             },
                               {
                                   header: 'Phone Number',
                                   flex: 1,
                                   dataIndex: 'phone'
                               }
                                               ]

                                           },
                                   ],

                                   dockedItems: [
                   {
                       xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                       itemId: 'pagingLog',
                       store: userStore1,
                       dock: 'bottom',
                       displayInfo: true,
                   },
                                   ]
                               },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'panel',
                                    region: 'center',

                                    items: [
                                            {
                                                xtype: 'grid',

                                                store: userStore2,
                                                columns: [
                              {
                                  header: 'Name',
                                  width: 100,
                                  sortable: false,
                                  hideable: false,
                                  dataIndex: 'name'
                              },
                              {
                                  header: 'Email Address',
                                  width: 150,
                                  dataIndex: 'email',
                              },
                                {
                                    header: 'Phone Number',
                                    flex: 1,
                                    dataIndex: 'phone'
                                }
                                                ]

                                            },
                                    ],

                                    dockedItems: [
                 {
                     xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                     itemId: 'pagingLog',
                     store: userStore2,
                     dock: 'bottom',
                     displayInfo: true,
                 }]
                                },

                                {
                                    xtype: 'panel',
                                    region: 'south',

                                    items: [
                                            {

                                                xtype: 'grid',

                                                id: 'GridId',
                                                store: userStore,
                                                columns: [
                                                    {
                                                        header: 'Name',
                                                        width: 100,
                                                        sortable: false,
                                                        hideable: false,
                                                        dataIndex: 'name'
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        header: 'Email Address',
                                                        width: 150,
                                                        dataIndex: 'email',
                                                    },
                                                      {
                                                          header: 'Phone Number',
                                                          flex: 1,
                                                          dataIndex: 'phone'
                                                      }
                                                ]
                                            }],
                                    dockedItems: [
{
    xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
    itemId: 'pagingLog',
    store: userStore,
    dock: 'bottom',
    displayInfo: true,
}]

                                }]
                    }]

            }).show();
        });
```

Comment: I thank you for the code snippet above. I run this in a jsfiddle, and it seems to load them fine.
But, when I run this from the console on a page in our app, all three grids load fine, but only 1 toolbar works. 
I'm going to guess that this is an issue with the older version of extjs which EXT.NET is using. 

Thanks to all for their suggestions and support. I appreciate it.